# Quaternion to Roll Pitch Yaw

Tags: quaternions

Where can I find a function (preferably written in php), that converts Quaternion rotation to 3D rotation (Roll Pitch Yaw) AND also solves gimbal lock problem (does not return NaN at gimbal lock angles). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not PHP, but C++. It should be easy to transfer to PHP. Invalid/gimbal cases can be seen where either rotateX, rotateY or rotateZ is not assinged because the value would be NaN.

```
        //Our Quaternion is defined by qx,qy,qz,qw
        double qx;
        double qy;
        double qz;
        double qw;          

        double rotateXa0 = 2.0*(qy*qz + qw*qx);
        double rotateXa1 = qw*qw - qx*qx - qy*qy + qz*qz;
        double rotateX = 0.0;
        if (rotateXa0 != 0.0 && rotateXa1 != 0.0) 
            rotateX = atan2(rotateXa0, rotateXa1);

        double rotateYa0 = -2.0*(qx*qz - qw*qy);
        double rotateY = 0.0;
        if( rotateYa0 >= 1.0 )
            rotateY = M_PI/2.0;
        else if( rotateYa0 <= -1.0 )
            rotateY = -M_PI/2.0;
        else rotateY = asin(rotateYa0);

        double rotateZa0 = 2.0*(qx*qy + qw*qz);
        double rotateZa1 = qw*qw + qx*qx - qy*qy - qz*qz;
        double rotateZ = 0.0;
        if (rotateZa0 != 0.0 && rotateZa1 != 0.0)
            rotateZ = atan2(rotateZa0, rotateZa1);
```